# API call made using requests in Python 3 returns HTML not JSON

Tags: python-3.x, api, curl, python-requests, payu

I'm using Python 3.7 and requests 2.21.0 to integrate payment gateway.

I have the following example form sandbox which works as expected (returns JSON):

```
curl -X POST https://secure.snd.payu.com/api/v2_1/orders \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer d9a4536e-62ba-4f60-8017-6053211d3f47" \
-d '{
    "notifyUrl": "https://your.eshop.com/notify",
    "customerIp": "127.0.0.1",
    "merchantPosId": "300746",
    "description": "RTV market",
    "currencyCode": "PLN",
    "totalAmount": "21000",
    "buyer": {
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        "phone": "654111654",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "language": "pl"
    },
    "settings":{
        "invoiceDisabled":"true"
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "name": "Wireless Mouse for Laptop",
            "unitPrice": "15000",
            "quantity": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "HDMI cable",
            "unitPrice": "6000",
            "quantity": "1"
        }
    ]
}'
```

On the other hand, I have the following Python code

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://secure.snd.payu.com/api/v2_1/orders"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer d9a4536e-62ba-4f60-8017-6053211d3f47"
}
data = {
    "notifyUrl": "https://your.eshop.com/notify",
    "customerIp": "127.0.0.1",
    "merchantPosId": "300746",
    "description": "RTV market",
    "currencyCode": "PLN",
    "totalAmount": "21000",
    "buyer": {
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        "phone": "654111654",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "language": "pl"
    },
    "settings":{
        "invoiceDisabled":"true"
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "name": "Wireless Mouse for Laptop",
            "unitPrice": "15000",
            "quantity": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "HDMI cable",
            "unitPrice": "6000",
            "quantity": "1"
        }
    ]
}

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

However, instead of JSON response, I'm getting HTML. Any ideas why? When using Python 2.7 I've used `urllib` and it worked but using `urllib` to make a call in Python 3.7 produces exactly the same effect, that is HTML instead of JSON.

Response should look like

```
{ 
   "status":{ 
      "statusCode":"SUCCESS",
   },
   "redirectUri":"{payment_summary_redirection_url}",
   "orderId":"WZHF5FFDRJ140731GUEST000P01",
   "extOrderId":"{YOUR_EXT_ORDER_ID}",
}
```

Comment: What does the HTML say that is being returned?

Comment: It's a normal HTML file which looks like it would load the next step, that is like it would follow redirect_url which is in response.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks! That was it... it is enough to add `allow_redirects=False`.

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

It was enough to add `allow_redirects=False`.